# Restangular POST fails https:// OPTIONS pass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ssl, https, restangular

I was able to convert most of my existing services to use Restangular. Everything apart from `POST` is working properly.

#### Original `POST` service that *works*

```
app.service('APIService', function($http, $q){
...
this.post = function(api, route, params){
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url : base_urls[api] + route,
            method : 'POST',
            data : params,
            withCredentials: true,
            useXDomain : true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

            }
        }).success(function(data){
            d.resolve(data);
            try{
               toastr.success(toastMsg[route].win, 'Success');  
            } catch(err){}

        }).error(function(data){
            d.reject(data);
            try{
                toastr.error(toastMsg[route].fail, 'Whoops');
            } catch(err){}

        });
        return d.promise;
    }
});
```

#### Which is used like this:

```
app.controller('AuthController', function($scope, APIService){
    $scope.login = function(username_or_email, password, redirectUrl){
        APIService.post('root', '/login', {
            'username_or_email' : username_or_email, 
            'password' : password
        }).then(function(r){

        if(r.success){
            window.location = redirectUrl;
        }else
        {
          // handle this 
        }
      });
   };
});
```

#### Conversion to Restangular

```
app.controller('AuthController', function ($scope, toastrFactory, Restangular) {
    $scope.login = function (username_or_email, password, redirectUrl) {
        var login = Restangular.one('auth'),
            creds = {
                'username_or_email': username_or_email,
                'password': password
            };


        login.post('login', creds).then(function (r) {
            window.location = redirectUrl || '/profile';
        }, function () {
            toastrFactory.error(['Error', 'Login not successful'])
        })
    };
});
```

The above fails the pre-flight `OPTIONS` pass, and gives up. What is the difference between my original service and the Restangular call I'm trying to use?

Worth noting I did set default config params for Restangular (to mirror the original service)

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://dev.foo.com/');
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({
        withCredentials: true,
            useXDomain : true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

            }
    });
```

What's strange is my Restangular `GET`s that require credentials on https:// WORK, and successfully pass the `OPTIONS` phase, and manage to send cookie data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the actual route you are trying to reach, but the `Restangular.one('auth')` seems like you'd need to define the resource identifier (eg. `POST /auth/123?username_or_email=moi`).

If you're trying to reach `POST /auth?username_or_email=moi` (with your `cred` in the HTTP parameters), then try `Restangular.all('auth')`.

If this didn't solve the problem, please provide the URI you're seeing in the browser's network inspector along with the URI you'd want to reach.